# Can I run CTS if there is no external SD card slot on the Android device and how?

Tags: android, cts

I am assigned to run CTS on our Android device (Android TV). However, no SD card slot is in the design.

Can I still run CTS without any SD card? If I can what should I do to store media data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can run CTS without SD card implemented on device. Android is not mandated SDCard support. 
Example, Pixel devices does not support SD card, but they passed android CTS certification.